# Dereferencing struct pointer in pthread

Tags: c++, pointers, pthreads

I need to pass a structure to a pthread and be able to change the values of the struct from the function the pthread will execute. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>

void *deal_cards(void* deck);

int main() {
    struct t_data {
        std::string name;
        std::string status;
        std::vector<int> hand;
        std::vector<int> *ptr_deck;
    };
    std::vector<int> deck = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> *p_deck = &deck;
    struct t_data player1_data = {"PLAYER 1", "lose", {}, p_deck};
    struct t_data *player1 = &player1_data;
    pthread_t p1;
    pthread_create (&p1, NULL, deal_cards, (void *) player1);
}

void* deal_cards (void* data) {
    (struct t_data*)->(std::vector<int>*)ptr_deck.push_back(3);
}
```

I get the following error when I run this

```
In function 'void* deal_cards (void*)
error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
error: expected ')' before 'struct'
```

In case it matters I'm compiling on Linux with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lpthreads
```

What am I missing and is that the right way to alter the values inside the structure?

Comment: C++ provides threading features as part of the standard library since C++11. These are easier to use and more type safe than pthread and should be used instead. See `std::thread` and `std::async`.

Comment: The code shown makes it seem like you may be using C examples or tutorials where as you seem to want to write C++ code. If you are trying to learn C++ make sure to use C++ learning material and not C learning material. The languages have some similarities but they are very different. Be sure to use materials made after 2011, the language has changed a lot since then.

Comment: The `struct` is defined locally in `main` so you cannot refer to it from another function like `deal_cards`. You won't be able to cast the pointer back to the right type.

Comment: `(struct t_data*)` is a cast, but what is it casting? Also note that the `data` parameter is not used anywhere in the function.

Comment: Once you have the first bit fixed up, the `(std::vector<int>*)` cast is unnecessary.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you have `ptr_deck` being used in the thread at the same time as `deck` being used in `main` things can get really ugly really fast. Multiple readers across threads is OK, but as soon as someone starts writing the program will become unpredictable unless you protect access to the vector with a a mutex or something very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous mistakes in your code:

- The `t_data` structure type is defined local to `main()`, so `deal_cards()` can't use it.
- `main()` is exiting, destroying its local variables, while the thread is still running.
- the syntax you are trying to use to access `push_back()` in `deal_cards()` is all wrong.  You are not referencing the `data` input parameter at all, that is what you should be type-casting to `t_data*`. And, you are type-casting `ptr_deck` to `std::vector<int>*`, which it is already typed as, so that cast is unnecessary.  And, since `ptr_deck` is a pointer, you need to use the `->` operator to access its `push_back()` method, not the `.` operator.

Also, while not strictly errors, you should also be aware of these:

- you are using `std::string` without `#include <string>`
- unlike in C, in C++ you don't need to prefix references to a structure type with the `struct` keyword.  Only the declaration of the structure type needs to use the `struct` keyword.

With that said, try this instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>

void* deal_cards(void* deck);

struct t_data {
    std::string name;
    std::string status;
    std::vector<int> hand;
    std::vector<int> *ptr_deck;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> deck = {1,2,3};
    t_data player1_data = {"PLAYER 1", "lose", {}, &deck};
    pthread_t p1;
    if (pthread_create (&p1, NULL, deal_cards, &player1_data) == 0) {
        pthread_join (p1, NULL);
        // use deck as needed...
    }
}

void* deal_cards (void* data) {
    static_cast<t_data*>(data)->ptr_deck->push_back(3);
    return NULL;
}
```

Though, you really should be using C++'s own `std::thread` class instead of pthreads directly:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

struct t_data {
    std::string name;
    std::string status;
    std::vector<int> hand;
    std::vector<int> *ptr_deck;
};

void deal_cards(t_data* deck);

int main() {
    std::vector<int> deck = {1,2,3};
    t_data player1_data = {"PLAYER 1", "lose", {}, &deck};
    std::thread p1(deal_cards, &player1_data);
    p1.join();
    // use deck as needed...
}

void deal_cards (t_data* data) {
    data->ptr_deck->push_back(3);
}
```